# HTML5 Video with no sound in start with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jquery video plugin for a video background. thing is that, i want no sound when the page loads. if i click unmute button, then sound plays. the button works perfectly. but problem is page load with no sound. here is my code:

```
$('.video-background').videobackground({
        videoSource: [['video/video1.mp4', 'video/mp4'],
            ['video/video1.webm', 'video/webm'], 
            ['video/video1.ogv', 'video/ogg']], 
        controlPosition: '#controls',
        loop: true,
        muted: true,
        loadedCallback: function() {
            //$(this).videobackground('mute');
            //$('video').attr('muted', 'muted');
        },
        preloadHtml: '',
        preloadCallback: function() {
            //alert("anni");
            $(this).videobackground('mute');
        }
    });
```

You can see that i was trying with "loadedCallback"  and "preloadCallback" options and calling the "mute" method. but no luck. can anyone help me?

plugin directory: https://github.com/georgepaterson/jquery-videobackground
example site: http://www.ycoyacht.com/ (I want something like this)

Comment: did you try `this.volume = 0`

Comment: or `this.muted = true` ?

Comment: You mean in "preloadCallback"?